# Issues with UIWebView submitting app to appstore (ionic app)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, uiwebview, capacitor

Can't seem's to get rid of UIWebView, Tried it all both using Cordova and Capacitor.
Can anyone shed a light on this?

```
PLUGINS:
    "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "0.6.8",
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^2.4.6",
    "@capacitor/core": "^2.4.6",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^2.4.6",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/clipboard": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^4.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/native-geocoder": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.10.0",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.11",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/google-maps": "^3.2.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.38.1",
    "call-number": "^1.0.1",
    "card.io.cordova.mobilesdk": "^2.1.0",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
    "cordova-ios": "5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-lib": "3.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": "^3.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "firebase": "^6.1.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "2.11.2",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
```

```
local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

```
System:
    Node : v8.9.3
    npm  : 5.5.1 
    OS   : macOS
```

Comment: Have you checked out the docs? https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/wkwebview/

Comment: I think one of your plugin using `UIWebView` check documentation of your plugins. What version of Cordova platform IOS did you use?

Comment: Looks like you're using both Capacitor and Cordova. Maybe thats the reason.

Comment: I did everything, for Cordova I used the latest I think it was 5.1.2. Then after not succeeding, I moved to Capacitor. and the same issues.

Comment: @user1891769 What I mean is, it looks like you're using both together. Is that intended? I would try only using Capacitor.

Comment: I also removed Cordova completely, the same thing. Anyway, capacitor know's to work with Cordova also. I moved back to Cordova, Doing all over again, go over each plugin updating doing all needed tutorials, Nothing. Very fustrating.

Answer (score 0):

What's the exact complaint from Apple when you submit your app?

If it's really about UIWebView, you should search your entire codebase (including all plugins). The most likely reason is that there is still at least one place where UIWebView is referenced or used. You need to get rid of all of them.

Comment: ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

I do see lot's of places when searching from Xcode

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this, probably missing 2 more plugins:

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr

I have installed them and remove and add the ios platform and all came to work. Thank you all for your help.